# How do I encode URLs containing spaces or special characters in Go?

Tags: go

I have a URL containing spaces and special characters, like the following example:

```
http://localhost:8182/graphs/graph/tp/gremlin?script=g.addVertex(['id':'0af69422 5be','date':'1968-01-16 00:00:00 +0000 UTC'])
```

How can I encode URLs like this in Go?

Answer (score 8):

Url encoding is provided in the [`net/url`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/) package. You have functions such as:

```
url.QueryEscape("g.addVertex(['id':'0af69422 5be','date':'1968-01-16 00:00:00 +0000 UTC'])")
```

Which gives you:

> g.addVertex%28%5B%27id%27%3A%270af69422+5be%27%2C%27date%27%3A%271968-01-16+00%3A00%3A00+%2B0000+UTC%27%5D%29

Also check out [url.URL](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) and [url.Values](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values). Depending on your needs, these will solve it for you.

If you only have the entire URL you can try to parse it and then re-encode the broken query part like this:

```
u, err := url.Parse("http://localhost:8182/graphs/graph/tp/gremlin?script=g.addVertex(['id':'0af69422 5be','date':'1968-01-16 00:00:00 +0000 UTC'])")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}   
u.RawQuery = u.Query().Encode()
fmt.Println(u)
```

However, be careful. If the string contains and ampersands (&) or hashmarks (#), it will not give the result you are expecting.

Comment: http://someaddress.com/gremlin?script=g.addVertex([,'date_of_birth':'1968-01-16 00:00:00 +0000 UTC','full_birth_time':'1968-01-16 03:33:00 +0000 UTC'])

to http://someaddress.com/gremlin?script=g.addVertex%28[%27date_of_birth%27:%271968-01-16%2000:00:00%20+0000%20UTC%27,%27full_birth_time%27:%271968-01-16%2003:33:00%20+0000%20UTC%27]%29

Comment: @PriyadarshiniRavi I've updated the answer with an example of parsing. But as I've mentioned: this can cause trouble as characters like & and # serves other functions.